# How to assign multiple values to one variable

Tags: python

I have a variable called enemy. I want that variable to contain multiple values such as speed, attack, defense. How would I do this? Or am I better off using a class and function? If so some help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this...

Comment: Have you glanced at the documentation, atleast once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this in multiple ways. Either store a dictionary like so

```
enemy1 = dict(name = "gargoyle",
              strength = 30,
              armour = 25,
              health = 50)
```

or a list (which is positional rather than name based)

```
enemy1 = ['gargoyle', 30, 25, 50]
```

I'd use a class like so though

```
class Enemy(object):
   def __init__(self, name, strength, armour, health):
      self.name = name
      # Rest of the attributes
```

This way, you can encapsulate "enemy functionality" into a single object and move it around. A lot easier than throwing around a dictionary. You can also add methods like `attack`, etc. to the class to make your enemy more lifelike and your code more readable.

Comment: Why is it easier to pass around an Enemy object than a dictionary?

Comment: Perhaps "move it around" was a bad choice of words. I meant that putting the state and the methods to manipulate it into a single unit (in this case, an object) will be more manageable than a bunch of unrelated functions operating on a generic data structure.

Comment: Ah yes that is undoubtfully true

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a `tuple`.

```
enemy = (speed, attack, defense)
```

Of course, if you plan on manipulating this using functions etc., you would be better off creating an `enemy` class.

```
class Enemy:
    # Your code.
```

Comment: Just saying, if he wants to mutate the value (like leveling up), tuples are probably not the way to go.

Comment: Using `namedtuple` and `_replace` would be the way to go.

Comment: I'd use a full fledged class. An `enemy` has to be able to do things (like `attack` etc.) and not just hold attributes.